# how to implement the pagination using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, pagination

I want to implement the pagination with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter Class.

I have found a lot of sources on google to implement it. 
But failed.

When I scroll down the screen and If I reached at the end of items of a page.
I want to display three items per a page.

```
public class LoggedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button logOutButton, postPageButton;
    private Session session;
    private RecyclerView mPostList;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private static Activity thisActivity = null;

    private Parcelable mLayoutManagerSavedState;

    public static int orderNum = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged);

    thisActivity = this;

    logOutButton = findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
    postPageButton = findViewById(R.id.postButton);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("post");

    mPostList = findViewById(R.id.post_list);
    mPostList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mPostList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");

    session = new Session(this);
    if(!session.loggedIn()){
        logout();
    }

    logOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logout();
        }
    });

    postPageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoggedActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            intent.putExtra("username", username);
        }
    });

}
```

Code below, There is my Firebase Recycler Adapter which has the method 'populate viewholder'

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final Query DBquery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("post").orderByChild("count");
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(
            Post.class,
            R.layout.post_row,
            PostViewHolder.class,
            DBquery
//                mDatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
            viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
            viewHolder.init(position, model);
        }
    };
    mPostList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        TextView post_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        post_title.setText(title);
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc){

        TextView post_desc = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
        post_desc.setText(desc);
    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
        ImageView post_image = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);

        Glide.with(ctx)
                .load(image)
                .into(post_image);
    }

    public void setDate(String date){

        TextView post_date = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
        post_date.setText(date);
    }

    public void init(final int position, final Post model){
        mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "게시물로 이동", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity, MyPostActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", model.getImage());
                intent.putExtra("title", model.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("text", model.getDesc());
                thisActivity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}


private void logout(){
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    session.setLoggedIn(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(LoggedActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Given that [pagination has been covered quite regularly before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+pagination), where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen // Hello. Frank. I've found methods startAt, LimitToFirst or Last. So, I am approaching it I think. But I didn't find anyone who succeeded to implement the pagination with firebase Recycler Adapter on stackoverflow. Oh, this word can be kind of offensive or arrogant. But I found them hard and failed. So, I don't know how to use startAt or LimitToFirst with it in my code. and other developer said to me that the pagination is impossible with Firebase Recycler Adapter when I use the real time database. but I am guessing there is a way to implement it.

Comment: Using the query methods you mentioned sounds like a good approach. think about the query you pass in to the adapter. How will you modify that as the user scrolls, keeping in mind that FirebaseUI's adapters can only use a single query?